# Prove there exists a basis $v_1, \dots, v_5$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

To prove there exists a basis $v_1, \dots, v_5$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{5} \\ \sqrt{7} \\ \sqrt{11} \end{pmatrix}$, one way of doing it would be to construct four vectors linearly independent with $v_1$ but we only need prove the existence. Another way, would be to iteratively pick $v_2$ not in the span of $v_2$, that is not a multiple of $v_1$ and then $v_3$ not in the span of $v_1,v_2$ etc. But maybe it is neater to use use the fact that every linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a basis. So we know there exists $v_1, \dots v_4$ which is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, but then we do not know if $v_1$ could be a linear combination of them...

Comment: You may take $v_k$ as $(2^{k/2},3^{k/2},5^{k/2},7^{k/2},11^{k/2})$ and exploit the non-vanishing of the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Or just take $v_2=(0,1,0,0,0),v_3=(0,0,1,0,0),v_4=(0,0,0,1,0),v_5=(0,0,0,0,1)$.

Comment: $\mathbb R^4$ isn’t a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$, though the latter certainly has subspaces isomorphic to it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Add to $v_1$ four (different) vectors of the standard basis $\{e_i\}$.

Comment: Just some second after the comment of @Jack.......

Answer (score 0):

Decompose $\mathbb R^5$ into $V\oplus V^\perp$, where $V = \operatorname{span}{\{v_1\}}$. $v_1\notin V^\perp$, so that adding it to any basis of $V^\perp$ will give a linearly-independent set of vectors.